Event aren't listened
I've tried to create a channel and the channel are listened
{
    "event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded",
    "data":"{}",
    "channel":"private-teacher"
}

I did configure the channels.php to broadcast and echo.js to listen the specific channel
RatingUpdatedEvent::dispatch($teacherData);

But every time I dispatch an event its not listened instead the data changes as soon as I reload the page or the sqlite
My previous code using the same approach did work, except this one I'm using it to update specific column on a table real-time without updating the whole rows
I did try change the method, like shouldBroadcast vs shouldBroadcastNow, switching between a channel and a privatechannel. or maybe because i try to use the create approach for updatedevent but either way i still don't quite get what's going on
<?php

    namespace App\Events;

    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
    use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

    class RatingUpdatedEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
    {
        use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(public array $teacher)
    {


        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new PrivateChannel('teacher'),
        ];
    }
}

